# Trying to compile React Native app and I am getting an error about React.js not existing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to compile my first React Native project, and it all works fine from the CLI, until I try to install a new library.

After installing any library, I get various errors, culminating in this:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `react` from file `/Users/myname/Desktop/Projects/ProjectName/App.js`, the package `/Users/myname/Desktop/Projects/ProjectName/node_modules/react/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/myname/Desktop/Projects/ProjectName/node_modules/react/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

I have, indeed, confirmed that those files exist.

What is going on here? I'm constantly having these errors as I am trying to use React Native, even when rebuilding the app multiple times and trying over.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following steps:

1. Stop metro bundler
2. Delete node_modules folder
3. cd into your project folder and run:

   'npm install'